# Angular2-how to remove item in ng-template by ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-template

I just want to remove item in ngFor,but when I click the remove button,It will always reload the page.I know there is problem in ng-template.Is there any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

here is the code:

```
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true" #acc="ngbAccordion" class="ngb-accordion" activeIds="ngb0">
     <ngb-panel *ngFor="let stock of StockInvestForecast;let i = index" id="ngb{{i}}">
        <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
           <span>
              <h4 class="text-purple">{{stock.StockName}}</h4>
              <button type="button" (click)="StockInvestForecast.splice(i,1)" class="btn icon-close-btn">
                <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
              </button>
          </span>
      </ng-template>
</ngb-accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordion uses `a`(anchor) with blank `href`(href=""), when you click on `button` from header section, it bubble up that event and fires `href`. That tends to change the `URL` to `""`(blank), but then you have default redirect, it is redirecting to common page. You have to prevent the event to be propagated up, using `.preventDefault()` on title of accordion.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn icon-close-btn"
     (click)="$event.preventDefault();StockInvestForecast.splice(i,1)">
    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
 </button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but it dose not work.Still redirect to the index page and reload.I think there is problem with <ng-template>,because if I use <div> instead of <accordion> and <ng-template>,it works well.

Comment: @Gracian I don't get it

Comment: According to your answer,I add "$event.preventDefault();" and it works.